Conceptual understanding of phase lag in LTI system
I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong trying to find the phase lag of this LTI system. I am looking at the plots of the input signal (blue) and system response (orange). I can tell the gain is 2 by looking at the relative amplitudes. I can't tell what the phase lag is.


Here's what I know. The phase lag is how far the phase of the system response is behind the input signal in radians. I think I should be able to find that by seeing how far along the x axis there is between the peak of the output signal (orange) and the peak of the input signal (blue) which looks like $\pi/15$ from the desmos plot above. If I understand correctly, the x axis is time, so $\pi/15$ is the time lag notated $t_0$, which is related to phase lag $\theta$ like this:
$$t_0 = \theta / \omega$$
where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the input signal (in this case 5, I think). So:
$$\pi/15 = \theta / 5$$
$$\pi/3 = \theta$$
But when I try entering $\pi/3$ into the question, it's also incorrect; maybe I need to do an additional step to convert to radians?
I am very new to LTI systems (I majored in Computer Science and work as a data scientist, so these concepts and terms are pretty far outside my usual field.) I want to check that I  understand conceptually what phase lag is, what the units should be, etc., before I move on. Thank you!

Welcome to MSE! I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Thanks, that second link was a helpful quick example - hopefully easier to read now

For the error being made here, a hint is to consider: If the phase lag is $\pi/3$, the output signal should peak $\pi/3$ radians after the intput signal. But in your graph, which signal peaks first?

Hmm, I think I see what you're saying. I had interpreted being "behind" as being to the left but it actually meant "happening at a later time point" which in this graph would be to the right.

If you want to read the phase lag off of the graph, it's important to not get mixed up between which peak happens first. In the present case, the peak of the output signal at $5t=-\pi/3$ means that the input lags the output by $\pi/3$. But the phase lag is defined the other way around, so you should instead locate an output peak and determine how much earlier ("to the left") the input peak occured. That yields a phase lag of $2\pi-\pi/3=5\pi/3$ instead.
That said, it's a good idea to know how to compute phase lag directly from the functions without having access to the graph. Given that the input is of the form $\cos(5 t)$ this amounts to expressing the output as $A\cos(5t-\phi)$. Here $A>0$ is the gain and $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$ is the phase lag. If we use the angle-addition theorem on this output form, we get
$$A\cos(5t-\phi)=A\cos(5t)\cos \phi+A\sin(5t)\sin \phi$$
Comparing this with the actual output we identify $(A\cos \phi,A\sin\phi)=(1,-\sqrt{3})$. This amounts to expressing the point $(1,-\sqrt{3})$ in polar coordinates, and hence we immediately have the gain as $A=\sqrt{1^2+(-\sqrt{3})^2}=2$. Taking into account that $(1,-\sqrt{3})$ lies in the fourth quadrant, we conclude that the phase lag is $\phi=2\pi-\cos^{-1}(1/2)=5\pi/3$. (Or use the two-argument arctangent to avoid this domain issue in the first place.)

Another way to reach $\phi,A$ is via complex numbers. This ultimately amounts to writing $1-i\sqrt{3}$ in polar form, which we get as $2e^{-i\pi/3}=2e^{i 5\pi/3}$.
